# Cakephp controller tests use the wrong database

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

After the models I start with writing unittests for the controllers. I use CakePhp 2.5.1

```
<?php
App::uses('MediaController', 'Controller');

/**
* MediaController Test Case
*
*/
class MediaControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{

    /**
    * Fixtures
    *
    * @var array
    */
    public $fixtures = array(
        'app.media',....
    );


    /**
    * testView method
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function testView()
    {
        $result = $this->testAction('/media/view/2', array('return' => 'vars'));
        debug($result);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $result);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('media', $result);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('Media', $result['media']);
    }
```

I get the 
NotFoundException
Invalid media
Test case: MediaControllerTest(testView)

so I check and find out that the test is not using my testdatabase like the models do, but my default database, which contains no dataset with id 2.

Any idea why? As far as I see I have the setup like the book suggests.

Calamity Jane

Edit: I tried another setup for my Fixture, but it still fetches the wrong data for testing:

```
class MediaFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
     public $import = array('table' => 'media', 'connection' => 'test_seed', 'records' => true);
}
```

Here is my setup in the database.php:

```
    $this->default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host'       => 'localhost',
        'login'      => 'mylogin',
        'password'   => 'mysupersecretpw',
        'database'   => 'gkm_wap_dev',
        'prefix'     => 'sang_',
        'encoding'   => 'utf8'
    );

    $this->test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host'       => 'localhost',
        'login'      => 'mylogin',
        'password'   => 'mysupersecretpw',
        'database'   => 'gkm_wap_test',
        'prefix'     => 'sang_',
        'encoding'   => 'utf8'
    );
    $this->test_seed = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host'       => 'localhost',
        'login'      => 'mylogin',
        'password'   => 'mysupersecretpw',
        'database'   => 'gkm_wap_testseed',
        'prefix'     => 'sang_',
        'encoding'   => 'utf8'
    );
```

Comment: How do u fixed it? I have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I found no fix or help so far. It is a real mess and one reason I have no complete code coverage.
When I write tests for controllers I have the problem with all controllers. Really annoying.
Maybe we can find a solution together?

Comment: I In my case the problem was with cakes "Permission" model.
I debugged my code with xdebug step by step and found a solution for my particular case. For ACL there is a config i have to set in my setUp(): `Configure::write('Acl.database', 'test');`.  But i don't think that it will help with your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend to: 
Create parent class for all your TestControllers and in the `setUp()` method put:

`ConnectionManager::alias('test', 'default');`

Comment: What does it do? Faking that the default connection is in fact the test database?